# Measures of association, Concordant and Discordant

Tags: association-measure

I want to calculate concordant and discordant pairs on nx2 tables.

```
    __________________________

    |    Value1   |  Value2  |
    |_____________|__________|
    |    0.3434   | 1        |
    |    0.2132   | 2        |
    |    0.3      | 3.3245   |
    |    0.6      | 0.12321  |
    |    0.745234 | 523      |
    |    4        | 0.2134   |
    |    3        | 111      |
    |    .        | .        |
    |    .        | .        |
    |    .        | .        |
    |    .        | .        |
    |    .        | .        |
    |_____________|__________|
```

This is a n x 2 table. How can I calculate concordant and discordant pairs? I am sorry I can't find suitable question tag.

Comment: You can do an outer join of this table with itself, leading to a $n^2 \times 4$ table. From there, it is very simple.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But I couldn't understand sorry , Can you explain clearly ? Hmmm maybe using maths ?